# Which Linux distro has a first-class KDE desktop experience and is stable and simple?

Tags: linux, kde

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 currently and I love it for:
It just works for all hardware
Wide selection of packaged applications that are configured by `dpkg` scripts
Painless configuration for what matters (Wifi and wired connections, extra screens, power saving)
Very easy to install proprietary software

I want to switch to a KDE-based distros. But most choices seem to fall among:

1. second-rate KDE experience(not tweaked for anything, no native configuration tools)
2. Against proprietary software, very difficult to configure, brittle to many use cases, unstable (Mageia 2 was one)

I considered:

Debian: Its stable, but a bit untweaked and not satisfy my need of cutting edge

Kubuntu: Unstable, consumes too much CPU

---

I shortlisted Mint which is based on Ubuntu. And Maybe Aptosid. Are there better choices?

Answer (score 12):

openSUSE is a quite KDE centric Linux distribution. See more in this wiki entry:
http://en.opensuse.org/KDE

Answer (score 5):

If you want to live on the bleeding edge, try [Fedora's KDE spin](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/kde/). I've been using this ever since the GNOME 3 nightmare and it's been pretty close to flawless.

Comment: Can I easily install nonfree software and drivers easily?

Comment: more easily than openSUSE, not as easily as Kubuntu :)

Comment: I've never run into a non-free program I couldn't install, unless it was a Windows program :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like `openSuse` definitely try [Mandriva Linux](http://www.mandriva.com/en/linux/overview/). It's really good.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Chakra-OS](http://chakra-linux.org/), though it's not `dpkg` based as it branched off Arch Linux but it's currently under heavy development and completely KDE centric.

Answer (score 0):

[Siduction](http://siduction.org). It should even satisfy your need for bleeding edge, since it's basically Debian sid. Not exactly a fork - for example, you still use Debian repositories and just get a few additions including a siduction kernel and they try to quickly repair some things when it comes to that (well, it's sid, isn't it), even before fixes naturally propagate to Debian's repositories so is generally much more enjoyable experience than simply plain Debian sid).

I know your questions has "and is stable" condition but you also want bleeding edge which is usually a contradiciton, but if you know what you're doing and you check [the forums](http://siduction.org/index.php?name=PNphpBB2) for upgrade warnings before dist-upgrade, things are amazingly stable - I'd even say as stable as pretty much any other distro (with the notable exception of it's older brother, Debian stable ;)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a brilliant KDE experience - [openSUSE](http://www.opensuse.org/en/), [Chakra](http://chakra-linux.org/), Fedora.
Fedora, I must say, is simply the forerunner of all new implementations, adoptions.